# Nothing writing to file in python?

Tags: python, file

Here is my code so far:

```
import flickrapi
import osmapi
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from time import sleep

api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
secret_api_key = "xxxxxxxx"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

def obtainImages3():

    file = open('citylist.txt', 'r')
    file2  = open('obtainedImages.txt', 'a+')

    for line in file:

        fields = line.strip().split()
        city = fields[1]

        group_list = flickr.groups.search (api_key=api_key, text = city, per_page = 100)

        for group in group_list[0]:

            group_images = flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos (api_key=api_key, group_id = group.attrib['nsid'], has_geo = 1, extras = 'geo, tags, url_q')

            for image in group_images[0]:

                try:
                    photo_location = flickr.photos_geo_getLocation(photo_id=image.attrib['id'])
                    lat = float(photo_location[0][0].attrib['latitude'])
                    lon = float(photo_location[0][0].attrib['longitude'])

                    id = str(image.attrib['id'])
                    url = str(image.attrib['url_q'])

                    geolocator = Nominatim()
                    location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(lat, lon))
                    dict = location.raw
                    osmid = dict.get('osm_id', 'default_value_if_null_here')
                    osmtype = dict.get('osm_type', 'default_value_if_null_here')
                    osmaddress = dict.get('display_name', 'default_value_if_null_here')

                    sleep(1)

                    if(osmtype == 'node'):
                        print id
                        print url
                        print osmaddress

                        file2.write("%s" % id)
                        file2.write(' ')
                        file2.write("%s" % url)
                        file2.write(' ')
                        file2.write("%s" % lat)
                        file2.write(' ')
                        file2.write("%s" % lon)
                        file2.write(' ')
                        file2.write("%s" % osmaddress)
                        file2.write('\n')

            except Exception:
                pass

    file2.close()
    file.close()
obtainImages3()
```

The code is running fine without any errors and my print statements are working fine. However nothing is being written to the file.
I have used the same method for writing to a file in a very similar program and it worked perfectly but here it is not working. Can anyone suggest why this might be? Thank you!!

Comment: Can you reduce this to the smallest complete example that still exhibits the problem? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try adding file2.flush() after the file2.wirte('n')

Comment: "running without any errors" in this case means "catching and suppressing  errors without looking at them"

Comment: @RobertJacobs thank you youre file2.flush() suggestion worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this so I can get credit for answer that was in comment.

Try adding `file2.flush()` after the `file2.write('\n')`

Comment: If this works, then the close() function is either not being called or is not working.

Answer (score 3):

I think the file.close() function should go into the function node, because it is in a buffer. or, remove the "except Exception:" method, and see what you got.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, the file write is throwing an exception.  In your code, you are ignoring the exception.  Change the except statement to:

```
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

and you will see the error.  It probably cannot open the file.

Comment: the only error it prints is 'photo has no location info' which is the error I am passing in the question, it is not giving any file errors

Comment: @RyanKilkelly Figure out what type of error it is and *only* catch that type of error with the `except` block.

Comment: How is it attempting the file writes if it is throwing an exception on `location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(lat, lon))`?

Comment: A suggestion from above of just adding file2.flush() after writing to the file worked, thanks for your help anyways

Comment: Great!  Be careful with handling those exceptions though...ignoring exceptions is never good.  At least print them out so you remember there is an issue.